# Minimising domains to specific folders

Tags: bash, sed

Looking to change these url's: Looking at `cut -d'/' -f1,2,3,.. test`  Not sure if this the best method?

```
  https://www.example.com/images/fdgdfg4wretrgretg/cad0be71.jpg
  https://www.example.com/images/fdgdfg4w/cad0be71/32234/234234.jpg
  https://www.example.com/images//77777/dfgdfgdfg/cad0be71.jpg
```

Connvert into:

```
  https://www.example.com/images/fdgdfg4wretrgretg/
  https://www.example.com/images/fdgdfg4w/cad0be71/
  https://www.example.com/images//77777/
```

Comment: Seems fine. Are you having any problem with that? If so, let us know what so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using bash directly?

```
declare regexp='^(https?://[^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)?$'
if [[ "$url" =~ $regexp ]]; then
  url="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Since it supports regexp, this should work for most case.

And in a loop:

```
declare regexp='^(https?://[^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)?$'
while read -r url; do
  if [[ "$url" =~ $regexp ]]; then
    url="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "url: $url"
  else
    echo "error: mismatch $url"
  fi
done < domains.txt
```

Or use sed directly:

```
sed -E -e 's@^(https?://[^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)?$@\1@g' domains.txt
```

And if you need to do something more in bash (you may consider reading [the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) from Ed Morton comment):

```
while read -r url; do
  echo "url: $url"
done < <(sed -E -e 's@^(https?://[^/]+/[^/]+)(/.*)?$@\1@g' domains.txt)
```

Comment: `if [[ "$url" =~ $regexp ]];` could be just `if [[ $url =~ $regexp ]];` (in this context) right?

Comment: Make sure to add the rest of the code that'd be required to read the urls from a file and output the result (but first read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)).

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this right, but doesn't seem to work? my sample https://pastebin.com/nK3YQxNX

Comment: @TedLyngmo as a general rule, I always quote.

Comment: @JanetD I suppose you domains.txt contains a file, whereas one single url is expected. See update.